# Best way to store items after you fill your items storage?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I filled up my entire storage and need more room to store stuff.  I have now resorted to placing everything i can into a room on both the floor and the walls.  My walls are literally filled with clothing.  But the problem now is that all my rooms are now also full.  I have sold items I can easily DIY and also stored all my outside items outside.  I have max storage 1600 and my house is fully upgraded.  What else can I do to store items?

Comment: What are you storing that you need all 1600 slots? You can just use the catalog to access most clothes/furniture. that alone should free up slots. Materials i can see storing, but you still dont need 1600 slots worth of materials.

Comment: i buy all the clothes and furniture i dont have yet.  if i cannot buy the thing in the catalog or make it with DIY i keep it.  I also keep those things that are in a set.  Im going to have to make a checklist of items so that i can keep or sell as i need.  Can someone suggest one?

Comment: @fja3omega I use an ACNH app that has a built-in checklist for items

Answer (score 3):

You could create another switch account and make another character on the island to get another storage set. The only problem is that you will have another house to deal with which might bother you aesthetically.

Comment: I did this and thank goodness I kept up with it because yes it is a bother to see some rundown house on my island that doesn't fit my aesthetic and it was a bit annoying to play the second account. Luckily I had a friend help me and they enjoyed playing that villager until they got their own switch.

Answer (score 3):

There is a recent update where you can purchase a storage upgrade from Tom Nook for half a million bells. This may be useful to you.

Comment: just got it to 2400 storage.  Its already at 2200 though.  Cleaning up takes forever

Comment: @fja3omega If you use Discord, then you can join the many Animal Crossing New Horizons servers and try to sell or giveaway any extra stuff you have lying around.